# Using WPF on a DLL to create Images Dynamically (instead of GDI+)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, image, gdi+

I need to generate an image dynamically, and after I read the tutorial [here](http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/150676.aspx) I realize i can use all the controls and layouts from WPF to generate my rendering, and then save it as a JPG.
The idea is to use this instead of GDI+, which is quite primitive.

The question is, how to I create a regular dll file that would generate programatically a WPF canvas so then i can add controls to it and then ouput that to an image file. Keep in mind that it would be consumed by an ASP.NET application.

Any ideas somebody?

Comment: I found this link
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPF-Image-to-WebPage.aspx
I'll see if it works....

Comment: Seems to work for me, but who knows why he's using jpeg for an intermediate format.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That example has a good start but I've found it's got a lot of unneeded junk along with it. The main thing is that you don't need to have a separate WPF project.

Here's what to do:

- Reference PresentationCore, PresentationFramework and WindowsBase in your web project.
- Create a Canvas and other WPF objects programmatically in an STA thread.
- Call a few special methods on them to make sure they update outside of the context of a WPF app.
- Render them to an image with RenderTargetBitmap.
- Shut down the thread's dispatcher.
- Set the mime type and output the image with ASP.NET.

To make this more efficient you could re-use the same thread rather than creating a new one for each image. In that case you would only need to clean up the dispatcher when you shut down the thread.

Here's the full working code I have:

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Threading;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private byte[] imageBuffer;

    public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.RenderImage();

        Response.Clear();
        Response.ContentType = @"image/png";
        Response.BufferOutput = true;
        Response.BinaryWrite(this.imageBuffer);
        Response.Flush();
    }

    public void RenderImage()
    {
        Thread worker = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.RenderImageWorker));
        worker.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        worker.Name = "RenderImageWorker";
        worker.Start();
        worker.Join();
    }

    public void RenderImageWorker()
    {
        Canvas imageCanvas = new Canvas { Width = 600, Height = 200, Background = Brushes.Azure };

        TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();
        tb.Width = (double)400;
        //tb.Height = (double)200;
        tb.TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center;
        tb.Inlines.Add(new Run("This is "));
        tb.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run("bold")));
        tb.Inlines.Add(new Run(" text."));
        tb.FontSize = 30;
        tb.Foreground = Brushes.Blue;

        imageCanvas.Children.Add(tb);

        // Update layout
        imageCanvas.Measure(new Size(imageCanvas.Width, imageCanvas.Height));
        imageCanvas.Arrange(new Rect(new Size(imageCanvas.Width, imageCanvas.Height)));

        RenderTargetBitmap bitmapRenderer = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)imageCanvas.ActualWidth, (int)imageCanvas.ActualHeight, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        bitmapRenderer.Render(imageCanvas);

        PngBitmapEncoder png = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        png.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapRenderer));

        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            png.Save(memoryStream);
            this.imageBuffer = memoryStream.ToArray();
        }

        if (bitmapRenderer.Dispatcher.Thread.IsAlive)
        {
            bitmapRenderer.Dispatcher.InvokeShutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: would be better to do

if(!worker.Join(timeoutelapsed))
{
   worker.Abort();
}

instead in case something goes wrong ?

Comment: Calling Abort() on a thread is generally not a good programming practice: it can leave resources leaking and generally leave the program in a bad state. It's quite difficult to write code that behaves nicely when its thread is aborted.